# Can I cut off the 2 fuse from the wire & connect a new one with normal soldering?

Tags: electrical, wiring, soldering

I have a connector wire from rice cooker, which is faulty.

It consists of 2 fuses `sefuse sf139e 142c 10a` connected by some funny looking connector.

Please refer to the image here:
[image]
[image]

Either 1 of both fuses are blown. Before I order a new fuse, can I:

1. Cut off both fuses
2. Solder a new fuses with a normal wiring?

Can the normal soldering wire withstand the high temperature current?

Or am I better off to buy a new rice cooker to be at a safe side?

Comment: I would be leery of soldering, as the heat could damage the fuses.  However, if you clamped pliers or some such tightly on the wire while soldering, that would likely protect the fuses.  (Note that the "funny looking connectors" are bog standard crimp connections.)

Comment: Have you tested to see if fuses are working or not?  If wire gets hot enough to melt solder, you have other nasty problems to deal with.  To repair or replace depends price of parts compared to new, and the cause of problem in first place.  Blown fuse is usually only symptom of problem.

Comment: did something unusual happen prior to the cooker not working anymore?

Comment: @dandavis, nothing usual. Just I used multimeter to check connection between two end points, & there is no connection.

Comment: @crip659, how do I test the individual fuse?

Comment: Your multimeter will check them out for continuity, place a probe on each side of fuse.  They are good if meter beeps or shows zero/or near zero ohms.

Answer (score 2):

Those are thermal fuses if you mechanically twist the wire together prior to soldering you will probably be fine 142c is about 287f that is 1/2 the melting point of most solders but I would twist together or western Union splice prior to soldering and the new fuses should blow long before the solder melts. I have fixed coffee pots that have similar fuses same method / 60/40 Rosen core solder (its outside the cooking area if concerned about lead, or use lead free solder). I put heat sinks on the wires and a quick solder did it on more than 1 coffee pot.

Comment: fixed a few myself... needed my soldering gun instead of my soldering iron. +1

Comment: As long as you don’t over heat the fuses just about anything should work.

Comment: Please re-consider your answer. This important connection should actually NOT be soldered because a failed coil can overheat and potentially melt the solder before the fuse blows (if the fuse can and something metal or wet were touching for example), leaving a mains conductor dangling (a twist is hardly secure), which could produce a short, which could produce a fire. That's why it's crimped: safety, not cheapness; those connectors take more work ($$$) than solder, and they wouldn't add them if they didn't have to - they know how to heatsink.

Comment: @dandavis, did you suggest that both fuses should not be connected by a normal DIY soldering work?

Comment: @dandavis please read the answer the melting point of the solder is 2x of the fuse. Rice cookers and coffee pots do not use coils they use fire rods /  calrods or other similar heating elements, a good tight western Union splice would be sufficient alone but a better connection with solder is normal. Even mains power is allowed to be soldered by code and by manufacturers instructions.  I have 500 amp pin and sleeve plugs that require solder on the mains the ground is clamped,  but only solder on the 3 phase 480 conductors no twist even just solder.

Comment: @hunterex: there's a reason the maker spent more to not use solder; safety.

Comment: @dandavis a crimp made by a machine is much cheaper than someone making a splice and soldering, if you have a different opinion make it an answer code allows mains wiring to be connected by solder just not the ground.

Comment: @EdBeal: you make fine points, but solder can fail in a way a crimp can't under edge cases, which is why such connections are often crimped in appliances made to get hot.

Answer (score 0):

I would order new fuses instead of buying new rice cooker. Fuses are there to protect your rice cooker and not render it useless therefore buy new fuses and enjoy using it for many years to come. Typically, there would be markings on the fuses, just punch those in to google and I'm sure you'll find some online. I would crimp them and then solder over the crimp.