# What black wire is it & the connector at the rice cooker?

Tags: electrical, wiring, connectors, soldering

Related to my previous question [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/224895/can-i-cut-off-the-2-fuse-from-the-wire-connect-a-new-one-with-normal-soldering),

I made the **biggest mistake of my life** to cut the black wire instead of the thermal fuse wire.

I need to replace the entire black wire & its connector at the end.
[image]
overview of the entire broken wire

[image]
close-up photo shot of the connector

[image]
connector at the power supply

What is the black wire type?

Can I strip the black wire insulator and connect with the other black wire from [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/224895/can-i-cut-off-the-2-fuse-from-the-wire-connect-a-new-one-with-normal-soldering) by soldering?

If not, what suggestion can you offer for me to join the black wire?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like high temperature insulation on the wire.  For connection can solder or use a high temperature type connection, crimp or wire nut type.

Comment: If this is "the biggest mistake of your life" , you're very lucky. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The wire is called fixture wire it has a fiberglass looking outer braid and many times a very thin white Teflon type inner insulation. The size of the wire is based on the wattage of the cooker on the “spade” or disconnect that is a female and if in a hot area requires a high temp female crimp connector standard nickel plated copper may work but may not last long, the same with nickel plated copper splices when hot the copper may relax. It took me a few high temp repairs to find ~900 degree f crimp connectors, if you also posted about bad fuses a day or so ago I would solder the same as my other advice but in this case most insulation other than fiberglass/ high temp slide over will be the best option.

Comment: +1 for "took me a few high temp repairs to find ~900 degree f crimp connectors".  Hard to find... I usually buy mine from an appliance repair 
 store.